# Create view via Powershell : One or more field types are not installed properly

Tags: powershell, list-view

I'm trying to create some new views, here the code I use:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"  

$web = Get-SPWeb "SHAREPOINTSite/Projects/Test" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $View1Title="ViewTest"
    $View1Filter=    "<Where>
                        <And>
                        <Neq>
                            <FieldRef Name='ProjectRole'/>
                            <Value Type='Text'></Value>
                        </Neq>
                        </And>
                        </Where>"
    $View1Columns = @(("Attachments"),("Stakeholder Name") ,("Approval Role"))  
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Stakeholders")
$viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
    foreach($Field in $View1Columns)
        {
            $viewFields.Add($Field) > $null
        }
$viewRowLimit = 50
$viewPaged = $true
$viewDefaultView = $false


$newview = $list.Views.Add($View1Title, $viewFields, $View1Filter, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView)

Write-Host ("View '" + $newview.Title + "' created in list '" + $list.Title + "' on site " + $web.Url)
$newview.update()
$list.update()
$web.Dispose()
```

So when I execute my script everything works, I see the view in my view list and all settings are the one I put in the querry, but when I tried to apply this view, I get the following error message:

***One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.
Correlation ID:9bb3039f-ec30-90c7-a070-9ea838f613d6***

But if I go in my view setting and then I click on Ok(without modification), after that the view will works

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your query has an "And", even though there is only one condition. Remove the "And" and it should work fine.